# How does XCMP Queue work?

Tags: xcm, xcmp

Is `cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue` just an implementation for `HRMP` (relayed messages b/w sibling parachain) or is it the actual implementation of `XCMP` (Direct p2p messages b/w sibling parachains) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XCMP queue pallet in cumulus gets its message passed in from the relay chain via the para-inherents [validation data](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/2ec939221c4afb287a37373be04bd29b8f5a1d60/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L446). It is not doing direct para-to-para messaging but always uses the Relay chain in between (often referred to as ["XCMP-lite"](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-xcm-transport)).

The outbound messages from the queue are copied to the collation info by the parachain-system pallet at the end of every block. The Relay can then extract the messages when enacting a candidate [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/c5d7b2fd0d7ec492c12c5e2942aab16d7f62be36/runtime/parachains/src/inclusion/mod.rs#L910) and route them accordingly.